# How do missiles navigate and determine their orientation without GPS?

Tags: navigation, missiles, attitude, inertial-nav-system

When a missile is engaged in a GPS free tracking loop how is its internal orientation estimated with respect to ground?

I'm assuming this orientation is needed because the force of gravity will be impacting the missiles flight path and this needs to be compensated for, am I wrong? Do they all use IMU? The IMU I have looked at all have bad performance and the cost of extreme precision IMU is greater than the smaller missiles so that can't be the solution.

Comment: What kind of missiles are you referring to? Weapons, scientific or hobbyists? If the latter two, please specify some type/types. Among weapons cost is definitely not an issue...

Comment: I'm specifically referring to missiles with self guidance systems for target tracking, lets say simple heat seekers like the stinger. I don't think every stringer has a 100k IMU.

Comment: 1. highly likely this is classified or under NDA (what I know is, so no answer from me) 2. this is probably off-topic https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4292/1467

Comment: Basic missile guidance methodology is not classified, as it is simple vector calculus :)

Comment: Simple, [the missile knows where it is...](https://youtu.be/bZe5J8SVCYQ) ;-)

Comment: a question for you, asker:  what do you think GPS does?  Orientation directly from GPS is uncommon, but I know it's been done in multi-antenna systems.  Velocity directly from GPS is a bit of a hack (you can derive it directly from Doppler shift).  Really, it's meant for position.

Comment: Subverting how to read a marine radar for collision avoidance, about the simplest approach I can think of is to just steer to maintain a constant target bearing, providing the missile is faster then the target they will come together eventually. No need to worry about where the ground is or gravity or any of that stuff. It is not necessarily optimal,  but is cheap, and you don't even need range to target, just bearing.

Comment: Before asking "how", ask "if" or "whether".  Given high-speed aerodynamics, rocket propulsion, possible rotation of the missile, the multi-G accelerations of e.g. fighter aircraft trying to avoid the missile, gravity may be one of the lesser and least troublesome forces acting on it.

Comment: Are you talking about homing missiles that fly to and attack a specific target like a plane, or cruise missiles that fly to a specific geographic location? The answers are very different for the two, and explains why you have two contradictory answers.

Comment: Piggyback on what @ErinAnne said, I would question whether you could even get reasonably good GPS data in a missile given how fast it travels.

Comment: @Michael you can get GPS updates at up to 50 Hz, even at Mach 2.5 that's an update every 15 metres. It's even been used in guidable artillery shells https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M982_Excalibur

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modern missiles pretty much all determine their orientation via some sort of IMU. Note that you do not need super-expensive [RLG-IMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_laser_gyroscope), but you might get away with cheaper [MEMS-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_structure_gyroscope#MEMS_gyroscopes) IMUs (*1). However (and I cannot stress this enough), **it all depends on your specification**:

- If you know your attitude from your IMU, you can better control your missile as you now are able use feedback-control (*2). Therefore your control-loops can minimize some error. It is also able to compensate for gravity (as you observed) or can actually follow the reference-value of the guidance loop.
- You don't even necessarily *need* a velocity sensor (such as a GPS-unit or a pitot-tube), because you can at least roughly determine your velocity over the accelerometers, or via the known velocity of your missile at the end of the burn or via velocity dependent system dynamics. [Kalman Filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity-introducing-speed-estimates) are often used in determining the exact system states.

But again, it depends on your specifications. With very tight specifications, you generally need to achieve very high performance in your control loops, which is only possible if you have very good (e.g. expensive) sensor available. If you need to hit the third screw from the left of your target, then you need very precise and expensive sensors. If your warhead is powerful enough to obliterate the target in a 2km radius, you can figuratively just close your eyes and aim in the general direction.

The take-home message is (especially for closed loop control of any flying vehicle) is: Performance and robustness of a control loop are interchangable. The more performance you demand of a control loop, the less robust against sensor noise, external disturbances, system dynamic uncertainties etc. it will be. There are plenty of ways to overcome limitations of missing sensors etc. in order to do something cheaper, however it is up to the designer to check if the product is still be able to perform its task as intended.

**Foonotes:**

(*1): Expensive and cheap in the military context are a bit different. A cheap MEMS IMU might still cost several thousands of USD.
(*2): Of course you do not need an IMU to close a control loop. Early missile designs directly coupled the angle-to-target (as determined by the seeker) with corresponding fin-deflection. However the addition of an IMU and the corresponding data streams offers more data for possible control loops.

Answer (score 23):

As per comments, this question is referring to guided weapons such as Stinger (IR guidance).

Guided missiles that acquire their target via signal return, such as infrared, radar or laser designation ([Homing Guidance](https://man.fas.org/dod-101/navy/docs/fun/part15.htm), see section 16.4.2) have absolutely no need to "know" their orientation in space. A target lock is established pre or post launch and then maintained by missile sensors, and the sensor signal is then used to calculate necessary maneuvers to steer towards the target.

Any information regarding where in space and in what alignment in reference to earth the missile actually is, is useless: only the position with regards to the target is of importance, as reaching the target is a matter of actions within the frame of reference of the missile, not the earth: the target exist in certain three dimensional(* point in space in relation to the missile sensor. The guidance system updates this "situational image" at certain intervals (several times a second) and the difference between images is used to calculate the rate of change and then the necessary steering inputs.

Adding sensors and algorithms relating to spatial situation with regard to earth's frame of reference add unnecessary complexity (and thus extra fail modes) to this kind of weapons. Within the maneuverability envelope of these missiles the "direction" of gravity is not of crucial importance.

*)To be precise, whether 3-, or just 2-dimensional situation image is actually necessary is an interesting question, as the missiles of this sort are not "throttle-able", so they speed on at full power until target is destroyed or fuel is depleted. Actual or relative speed are therefore of no importance. However, some missiles do not need to impact the target to detonate, so they must have some way to determine the sufficient proximity to the target to arm and explode.

Comment: The issue is normally for control you need to know your orientation to predict system response because gravity has a huge influence on flight. It's possible some type of simple PID loop with respect to target center would be good enough for these systems even if some steady error exists but I have never seen the internal operation.

Comment: But basically every paper I have read on optimal control in this area assumes knowing full state(even more than orientation). For ground controlled rockets all this makes sense but if your missile is only guided by its internal sensor is much harder, this my question.

Comment: I will expound on this in the answer, pls standby.

Comment: The fuse is usually completely separate from the guidance system. It just detects an object in proximity at a certain threshold range, not its full 3D position.

Comment: @Jpe61 - "some way to determine the sufficient proximity to the target to arm and explode." Yes. That is called, wait for it...a "Proximity fuse". In the case of the AIM-9, it senses when it might be going "past" the target, and explodes. Hopefully punching many holes in it.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the concept of proximity fuse, but what exactly is the magic by which the said proximity fuse determines the proximity of the object @WPNSGuy

Comment: Proximity fuzes go back to WWII; the operation of those early units has long been declassified.  Wikipedia has a good article -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_fuze

Comment: @FourierFlux: In real missiles you face the tradeoff between more sensors and hitting your performance specifications. For example some short-range missiles do not need to know their exact velocity in order to achieve meaningfull good control, however then the control-system has to be robust enough to steer the rocket over broad enough velocity range. The same goes for attitude control: Sure a Laser-IMU is beneficial, but on a Stinger-type rocket, it might just not be absolutely *needed* when considering the specifications.

Comment: @FourierFlux it doesn't take GPS to know which way is down.  A 3-axis accelerometer will tell you that from the acceleration vector and how it differs from the thrust axis (even if PID isn't enough, which it might well be)

Comment: @Jpe61 - Early AIM-9 has an IR sensor for proximity. Later models (AIM-L and later) have a laser. The AIM-120 uses a pulse Doppler prox fuse.

Comment: @Therac : however, knowing the relative speed might be useful even for a proximity fuse. For example, in case of aircraft, it matters a lot whether the missile comes from the front or from the back. If it comes from the front and only arms after missing, all the shrapnel will fall far too far behind the target, as the relative speed is too high. But if it comes from behind, then overtaking and exploding can cause damage. What I mean, is that it might be of an advantage to detonate sooner if the relative speed is very high.

Comment: @vsz It would be useful. But practical fuses usually work on a simple principle: they arm after some seconds, then illuminate a sector in front of the missile, and if they detect a reflection, within their range, the fuse detonates instantly. The fuse won't arm at all if the missile misses.

Comment: @FourierFlux, A simple PID feedback loop is way more than enough. It does not matter whether the target is moving in the sights because the missile is falling with gravity, getting blown aside by wind or the target is moving. Just steer until the target stays still. You only need navigation system for long range.

Comment: @FourierFlux As I understand it, the thrust/acceleration on AA missiles is so great and the period of the feedback loop is so short, that gravity doesn't need to be taken into account.  AFAIK, there is no global/optimal path being plotted out, it's just doing adjustments very quickly with a lot of acceleration.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the answer given by @Jpe61, homing missiles use a technique called '[Proportional Navigation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_navigation)'. It is a surprisingly simple algorithm in which the missile attempts to keep the target on a constant bearing. As long as the missile is reducing the distance to the target this guarantees a hit.

This technique can be implemented using a PID controller where the error signal is the deviation from a constant bearing (detected on a photocell in the case of an IR seeker). The PID output then drives the control fin motors.

Comment: Exactly. It does. not even matter which way is up as losing altitude would cause the missile to drop below target (hence the target becomes above the missile) and thus automatically corrects the missile's attitude by steering onto target. Complicated IMUs are used more on cruise missiles and ICBMs that fly long ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Active Skyflash quoting the relevant part where it describes how the missile tracks the target:

http://www.ausairpower.net/skyflash-slammer.html

> The Active Skyflash seeker feeds the missile's Integrated Power and
> Control Unit (ICPU) with serial signals proportional to target
> line-of-sight difference from the missile's boresight in yaw and
> pitch, and with a signal proportional to target range. The missile is
> steered by cruciform wings, a pair each generating yaw and pitch
> inputs, with one pair differentially controlled to provide roll
> stabilisation. The wings are actuated by solenoid controlled
> hydraulics, the solenoids driven by DC amplifiers fed from digital to
> analogue converters (D/A).

Basically, the missile boresight, orientation, and where the seeker head is telling it the target is.